# How to use uniform boundedness principle

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $f_n$ be orthogonal sequence in Hilbert space and $\sum \langle f_n,g\rangle$ converges for all $g \in H$. Then show that $\sum f_n$ converges in Hilbert space.

I want to use the uniform boundedness principle to solve this but I have one problem with that. I think we should define $T_n = \sum\langle f_n,g\rangle f_n$ and then use UBC but I think if we take $T_n = \sum \langle f_n,g\rangle$ is also should work. So my problem is that which one is correct or both of them is working in this question?

Comment: No, the idea is wrong, you are not trying to represent $g$ in the basis $f_n$. (You would need to have $f_n$ normalized, and some completeness to be a basis.) You are trying to show that a weakly convergent sequence in a Hilbert space is already strongly convergent.

Comment: @nicomezi Oh okay. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

Define $$T_n: \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{C}$$ by $$T_n (g) =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left< f_k , g\right>$$
Let $$u_n =\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n f_k}{\left|\left| \sum_{k=1}^n f_k\right|\right|}$$ then $$||u_n|| =1$$
and $$|T_n (u_n ) |=\left|\left| \sum_{k=1}^n f_k\right|\right|$$
the above with some obvious observations implies that$$||T_n || =\left|\left| \sum_{k=1}^n f_k\right|\right|.$$
Now we know that $T_n $ converges for every $g$ therefore by Banach - Steinhaus theorem the sequence $$||T_n ||$$ is bounded.